# Flatten nested Hashmap in Java

Tags: java, recursion, hashmap, java-stream

I want to flatten a nested hashmap. For eg,

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap();
Map<String, Object> map2 = new HashMap();
Map<String, Object> map3 = new HashMap();
map3.put("key3", 123);
map2.put("key2", map3);
map2.put("key4", "test");
map.put("key1", map2);
map.put("key6", "test2");
```

This will have structure something similar to this:

```
{
 "key1" : {
            "key2" :  {"key3" : 123 },
            "key4" : "test"  
          },
 "key6" : "test2"
}
```

This should be flattened to a hashmap with structure similar to this:

```
{
    "key1.key2.key3" : 123,   
    "key1.key4" : "test",
    "key6" : "test2"
}
```

I tried solving this recursively in Java, but not able to produce the right form. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You're talking about a Hashmap, but posting data structure. Can you add a snippet of your Java code? This will make it easier for someone to create an answer that helps.

Comment: this is the structure of how data is stored inside the hashmap. However, I've updated it as well.

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question but storing Object in a map is really bad practice and allows for all kinds of difficult to handle problems. Look over the problem you're actually trying to solve and see if you can do it with typed maps instead.

Answer (score 2):

Can be acheived using [Stream#flatMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) and recursion.

`flatMapper()` will be recursively called and it will return a Stream of string builder with child keys appended.

```
public class NestedHashMap {

    private static Stream<StringBuilder> flatMapper(Map.Entry<String, Object> entrySet) {
        Object value = entrySet.getValue();
        if (value instanceof Map) {
            return ((Map<String, Object>) value).entrySet()
                                                .stream()
                                                .flatMap(NestedHashMap::flatMapper)
                                                .map(s -> s.insert(0, entrySet.getKey() + "."));

        }
        return Stream.of(new StringBuilder(entrySet.toString()));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // ... Code in the question

        System.out.println(map.entrySet()
                              .stream()
                              .flatMap(NestedHashMap::flatMapper)
                              .collect(Collectors.joining(",\n\t", "{\n\t", "\t\n}")));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
{
    key1.key2.key3=123,
    key1.key4=test,
    key6=test2  
}
```

Comment: can you suggest an answer without a stream?